# to_excel function merge cells when saving to Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

```
CompanyName    High Priority     QualityIssue
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer2         No              User
Customer3         No              Equipment
Customer1         No              Neither
Customer3         No              User
Customer3         Yes             User
Customer3         Yes             Equipment
Customer4         No              User
```

I want to count how many time each instance in `CompanyName` appears per every type of `QualityIssue` and sort by the number of appearance descend.

For example, by using this code:

```
df.groupby(["CompanyName ", "QualityIssue"]).size()
```

I get:

```
Out:

CompanyName       QualityIssue    Count
Customer2         User            1
Customer1         Neither         1
Customer4         User            1
Customer1         User            2
Customer3         Equipment       2
Customer3         User            2
```

Then I use :

```
out.to_frame().sort_values(by='Count').to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

And get :

```
CompanyName       QualityIssue    Count
Customer2         User            1
Customer1         Neither         1
Customer4         User            1
Customer1         User            2
Customer3         Equipment       2
                  User            2
```

Notice that in the last 2 rows :

```
Customer3         Equipment       2
                  User            2
```

`Customer3`'s row is merged with the next row, so `Customer3` is 1 cell created by merging 2 rows and the other info appear on separate rows. The problem here is if I want to save the Excel file to `.csv` I will get 2 rows, first is the `Customer3 Equipment 2` and the second one is empty cell `User 2`, but it should be `Customer3` instead of empty cell.

Any solution to not merge the cells when saving to Excel but to have the name repeated? as in the output of python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `columns` from `MultiIndex`:

```
out.reset_index().sort_values(by='Count').to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! On another topic, is there a way to get in a new vector the last column? For example to have a variable that would keep only the count column. If i say out['count'] I get all the data just like printing out alone.

Comment: Do you think `out[['count']].reset_index().sort_values(by='Count').to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)` ?